# Lists of lists with foldl and replace elements that have occured before?

Tags: haskell, fold

I am developing a Pacman game and I need to compact the maze. So, for example, if one corridor of the maze is:

```
[(1, Wall),(1, Wall),(1, Wall),(1, Empty),(1, Food),(1, Food),(1, Empty),(1, Wall)]
```

We compact it in order to avoid repeating, so it looks like this:

```
[(3, Wall),(1, Empty),(2, Food),(1, Empty),(1, Wall)]
```

By now, I have the maze compacted in this format:

```
[
  [(5, Wall)],
 [(1, Wall), (2, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Wall)],
  [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
  [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
 [(1, Wall), (1, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
  [(5, Wall)],
]
```

But as we can see, some corridors(lines) are repeated. So in order to avoid it, the final maze compacted needed to look like this:

```
[ [(5, Wall)], 
 [(1, Wall), (2, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Wall)],
[(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
  Repeat 2,
 [(1, Wall), (1, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
  Repeat 0,
]
```

So, if the corridor has already occured in the maze, it will return Repeat n where n is the position it first appeared.

I've thought about foldl to traverse the list, but I probably need an aux function in the meanwhile but I am having trouble to develop it as I am only a beginner in haskell and programming xd So I accept suggestions, tips, articles anything that could help me! Thank you so much!

If maybe it helps, here are the type and data type being used:

```
type Instructions = [Instruction]
data Instruction = Instruct [(Int, Piece)]
               | Repeat Int
```

Comment: Is it important that it is a list-of-lists? It looks like it's easier to tackle the most general case where we have a list-of-T for any T (including lists), and we detect repeated elements. By the way, you can't change `[a,b,a,c]` to `[a,b,Repeat 0, c]` since all elements must have the same type, but you can instead have `[New a, New b, Repeat 0, New c]` with a custom type `data T a = New a | Repeat Int`.

Comment: @MillenaFreitas, probably you should look at [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group)/[`groupBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) and [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). If you provide some driver code, that would be useful too.

Comment: @MillenaFreitas, a code that we can copy, paste, compiler, and run. Preferrably a minimal working example, not the full code you're writing :P

Comment: @MillenaFreitas My suggestion is: don't focus on lists-of-lists, focus on lists-of-anything, which is more general than lists-of lists. Doing so you will create a program which will _also_ works on lists-of-lists. I can't see anything in your question which is really specific to lists-of-lists. Finding duplicates in a list-of-anything requires (essentially) the same code as finding them is a list-of-lists, and is less confusing.

Comment: @Enrico ohh okay ahah thank you!  The code that I have is for the format where the corridors are showed repeatedly, I don't have a code yet for the final maze compacted, by now I only have the idea of going through the list and accumulating the corridors(lines) and each time if there is one that has already appeared before, it would replace for Repeat n, but I'm stuck on how to start it :c

Comment: I understand, @MillenaFreitas, but your question has nothing to do with Pacman. You can "distill" the importand bit out of that (a list with things that can be repeated, where you want to compact the repetitions) and put it in a standalone script that we can load to work on it to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be a wise-ass, but *why* do you need to compact the maze?  The game will be easier to code if it runs on an uncompacted maze; and the source code will be easier to understand if it includes the uncompacted maze directly (or maybe an ASCII-graphics versions that is parsed into another uncompacted data structure).

Answer (score 1):

Given the data types:

```
type Instructions = [Instruction]
data Piece = Wall | Food Size
data Size = Little | Big
data Instruction = Instruct [(Int, Piece)]
                 | Repeat Int
```

and a partially compacted maze:

```
maze1 :: [[(Int, Piece)]]
maze1 =
  [ [(5, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (2, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (1, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(5, Wall)]
  ]
```

you can compact it using recursion.  At each recursive step, you need to check if the next `[(Int, Piece)]` item has already been output (so you can decide if it's a repeat), and to do this, you'll need to keep track of the list of instructions you've output so far.  The easiest way to do this, is to make the instructions you've already produced into an argument to your recursive function, so your recursive function will look like this:

```
compact' :: Instructions -> [[(Int, Piece)]] -> Instructions
compact' done (x:xs) = ...
```

where the right-hand side of this definition will process the next `x :: [(Int, Piece)]` using a list of instructions we've already done, namely `done :: Instructions`.

We'll do this by adding the `next` instruction to the list already `done` and recursing:

```
compact' done (x:xs) = compact' (done ++ [next]) xs
```

and then, when we run out of input, returning the full list:

```
compact' done [] = done
```

The only remaining step is to define `next`.  We can use `elemIndex` from `Data.List` to look up the position of `x` in `done`, if it's a repeat, like so:

```
where next = case elemIndex (Instruct x) done of
               Just pos -> Repeat pos
```

If it isn't found, we just add it as an `Instruct` instruction:

```
               Nothing -> Instruct x
```

To kick things off, we'll write a `compact` that starts the recursion with an empty `done = []`:

```
compact :: [[(Int, Piece)]] -> Instructions
compact input = compact' [] input
```

which can be written more simply as:

```
compact = compact' []
```

Getting the full program to compile requires us to add an appropriate import and some `deriving` clauses to the data types.  (`Eq` is needed to look the instruction up in the `done` list.)  The full program looks like:

```
import Data.List

type Instructions = [Instruction]
data Piece = Wall | Food Size deriving (Show, Eq)
data Size = Little | Big deriving (Show, Eq)
data Instruction = Instruct [(Int, Piece)]
                 | Repeat Int
                 deriving (Show, Eq)

maze1 :: [[(Int, Piece)]]
maze1 =
  [ [(5, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (2, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (1, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(5, Wall)]
  ]

compact :: [[(Int, Piece)]] -> Instructions
compact = compact' []
  where compact' :: Instructions -> [[(Int, Piece)]] -> Instructions
        compact' done (x:xs) = compact' (done ++ [next]) xs
          where next = case elemIndex (Instruct x) done of
                         Just pos -> Repeat pos
                         Nothing  -> Instruct x
        compact' done [] = done

main = print (compact maze1)
```

This is not a very efficient implementation, as it runs in quadratic time searching and re-searching the `done` list for every element added and using `done ++ [next]` to append an element in linear time.  However, you'd have to be writing a pretty enormous pacman game for this bad performance to be a real issue.

An alternative implementation that uses a `Map` to efficiently look up the positions might look like this.  It shows an alternative technique for the recursion where instead of building up a `done` list and then returning it at the end, we build up a `done` map but separately return the list, element by element without waiting until the end.  The type-level techniques here (e.g., the definition of `Compact a` parametrized by the type `a`) are a little more advanced, but you might find the approach interesting.  I think most Haskell programmers would consider this a reasonable production-level implementation (though some might use `mapAccumL` instead of the recursion).  Anyway, this is probably how I'd write it in "real code".

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- A general representation for lists of repeatable objects
type Compact a = [Repeatable a]
data Repeatable a = First a | Repeat Int deriving (Show)

data Piece = Wall | Food Size deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Size = Little | Big deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

compact :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Compact a
compact = compact' 0 Map.empty
  where compact' :: (Ord a) => Int -> Map.Map a Int -> [a] -> Compact a
        compact' pos done (x:xs) = next : compact' (pos + 1) done' xs
          where (next, done') = case Map.lookup x done of
                  Just pos -> (Repeat pos, done)
                  Nothing  -> (First x, Map.insert x pos done)
        compact' _ _ [] = []

maze1 :: [[(Int, Piece)]]
maze1 =
  [ [(5, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (2, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (3, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(1, Wall), (1, Food Little), (1, Food Big), (1, Food Little), (1, Wall)],
    [(5, Wall)]
  ]

main = do
  print (compact maze1)
  print (compact ["it","is","what","it","is"])
```

The `mapAccumL` version would look like this:

```
compact :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Compact a
compact = snd . mapAccumL step (0, Map.empty)
  where step (pos, done) x = ((pos + 1, done'), next)
          where (next, done') = case Map.lookup x done of
                  Just pos -> (Repeat pos, done)
                  Nothing  -> (First x, Map.insert x pos done)
```

Answer (score 0):

```hs
data Whatever = Wall | Empty | Food deriving(Eq, Show)
long = [(1, Wall),(1, Wall),(1, Wall),(1, Empty),(1, Food),(1, Food),(1, Empty),(1, Wall)]
```

you can do this:

```hs
map (\xs@((x,y):_) -> (length xs, y)) $ Data.List.group long
```

which gives

```hs
[(3,Wall),(1,Empty),(2,Food),(1,Empty),(1,Wall)]
```

Comment: Oh this is a way better way than what I have done xd 
But what I am struggling with is, for example, if I have this list: `[1,2,1,3,1,4]` I want it to return `[1,2,Repeat 0,3,Repeat 0,4]` 0 because is the first position that the number 1 occured in the list.

Comment: @MillenaFreitas, you cannot have that. A list has type `[a]`, where `a` is the type of the items in the list. `1`, `2`, and the other numbers have a type, whereas `Repeat 0` has another type. You cannot have objects of distinct type in the same list. If you want to do this repeat thing for saving space/improving performance, you should probably look at other data structures, I guess.

Comment: You're right! But in this case it was only an example to illustrate what I want to do, but I'm aware that I would have to do it accordingly with the data structures that I have. I was unfortunate in the example that I gave you, sorry!
If I have this list `[1,2,1,3,1,4]` and I want to replace the elements that have already occured before to the position it first occured so it would look like `[1,2, 0,3,0,4]` 0 because the number 1 appears first in the list at the position 0.

Comment: @MillenaFreitas, I think your example is still unfortunate. How do you transform `[1,2,1,3,1,2]`? It becomes `[1,2,0,3,0,1]`. Here the first 1 is a true 1, whereas the second 1 is the index of the first 2. Please, edit your question so that it's clear what you have at your disposal, what you want to achieve. And please, provide same code which runs.